# How to solve this exception??Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

i am new to hibernate and trying to persist a simple object in database.The data is getting saved in the table but then the following exception is thrown.
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

Here is my code,please help!

```
    @Transactional
public void addEmployee(Employee empObj) {
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>in DAO");

    Transaction tx = null;
    Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    try{
    tx=session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(empObj);
    tx.commit();
    }

    catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null)
             tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change your method code as follows:

```
@Transactional
public void addEmployee(Employee empObj) {
    Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(empObj);
}
```

If you have indeed configured Hibernate with Spring - as I guess you have, judging from the exception - then a Hibernate Platform Transaction Manager intercepts the method call (implied by `@Transactional`) and automatically starts a transaction for you. Since a transaction has already been opened per that session, a new one can't be opened.

Comment: Yes its working ,thanks!! now would you please explain to me when to use @Transactional?? what was wrong with my code??

Comment: so does @Transactional handles auto commit and rollback??doesn't one need to close the session after the transaction is over?

Comment: When you use `@Transactional`, as explained Spring opens one for you before the method call, and commits when the method end (or rolls back usually if exception occurs). Think of it as if Spring calls `session.beginTransaction()` before the method call, and `tx.commit();` afterwards

Comment: You never need to close a session as it's usually pinned to a Thread. Just transaction begin and commit | rollback which Spring does for you

Comment: another thing Orid,i found some codes where @Transactional is used at the service layer or in the class which calls the dao methods.could you please explain the the reason behind this or which is more appropriate?

Comment: It's more appropriate at the service layer, since you can span a transaction that uses more than a single DAO

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are mixing hibernate and spring transactions.
`@Transaction` is a Part of spring AOP and dose auto transaction handling. you have to have use only a transaction type in your code you can remove either one.